# mainwindow gets wider than screen size in Qt3

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt3

I have a maximized mainwindow with dockwidgets. When I increase width of the left dock area (by dragging) the mainwindow gets wider than screen size.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Qt3 is obsolete you should consider switching to Qt4

Comment: but i have to use Qt3 :(

Comment: Whatever the reason to still use Qt3, it must be a wrong one. ;)